# GCP Bucket upload fails to connect to oauth2 token when uploading large amount of images

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wrote an upload function in NodeJS for uploading of images into a google cloud bucket. The function works fine when I try to upload ~200 to 400 images. However, I tried upload a larger dataset (3000+ images), initially the uploading sequence seems fine and then it just suddenly throw an error. When I look at the bucket from google cloud console, it seems that only some of the images are uploaded.

I tried looking around to see if anyone encountered the same problem as me, but I cannot seem to find any similar cases. Would greatly appreciate it if someone can point me towards the right direction.

Here is my code for the gcp upload function.

```
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");
const gc = require("../config/gcp");

const uploadImages = async (req, pid, folder) => {
  let promises = [];
  const bucket = gc.bucket(pid);

  req.forEach(image => {
    const blob = bucket.file(`${folder}/${image.originalname}`);
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line security/detect-non-literal-fs-filename
      const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
        metadata: {
          contentType: image.mimetype,
        },
        resumable: false,
      });

      blobStream
        .on("finish", async () => {
          try {
            await blob.makePublic();
            resolve();
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
        })
        .on("error", err => {
          console.log(err.message);
          reject(err);
        })
        .end(image.buffer);
    });
    promises.push(promise);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      promises = [];
      console.log("Images Uploaded");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw Error(err.message);
    });
};
```

Here is the error I would suddenly receive in the midst of the upload sequence.

`Internal server error: Error: request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token failed, reason: connect EHOSTUNREACH 74.125.200.95:443`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the code is written right now, you're trying to perform every upload operation all at the same time, in parallel.  At some point with node.js, you hit the limit of active network connections you can carry at the same time.  This would happen if you were making a network request to any site, not just GCP.

I would suggest throttling the promises through an async queue, like [p-queue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-queue).  This is often how we write tests for these libraries!  I would start by limiting concurrency to ~25 concurrent operations, and then go from there.